# How can I access a part of this print out

Tags: ios

Not sure exactly how to word this but basically I am doing this:

```
unsigned int propCount = 0;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &propCount);

for(int idx = 0; idx < propCount; idx++) {
    objc_property_t prop = *(properties + idx);
    NSString *key = @(property_getName(prop));
    NSString *key2 = @(property_getAttributes(prop));

    NSLog(@"%@::%@", key,key2);
}
```

and it prints out

```
describeOther::T@"UITextField",&,N,V_describeOther
```

how can I assign "UITextField" to something or is it already assigned and I can access it like key2[1] or something??

EDIT:
I guess I could do a if statement with a contains constraint but not sure if thats the "cleanest" way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the range of the two double-quotes and extract the substring between those two ranges.

```
NSRange openQuote = [key2 rangeOfString:@"\""];
NSRange closeQuote = [key2 rangeOfString@"\"" options:NSBackwardsSearch];

NSUInteger start = openQuote.location + openQuote.length;
NSUInteger end = closeQuote.location;
NSRange nameRange = NSRangeMake(start, end - start);
NSString *name = [keys substringWithRange:nameRange);
```